# Read csv in r with special characters

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, read.table, read.csv

I am trying to read a data file into R with several delimited columns. Some columns have entries which are special characters (such as arrow). Read.table comes back with an error:

> incomplete final line found by readTableHeader

and does not read the file. Tried `UTF-8`, `UTF-16` coding options which didn't help either. Here is a small example file.

I am not able to reproduce the arrow in this question box, hence I am attaching the image of the notepad screen of a small file (`test1.txt`). 
Here is what I get when I try to open it.

```
test <- read.table("test1.TXT", header=T, sep=",", fileEncoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactor=F)
```

> Warning message: In read.table("test1.TXT", header = T, sep = ",",
>   fileEncoding = "UTF-8",  :   incomplete final line found by
>   readTableHeader on 'test1.TXT'

However, if I remove the second line (with the special character) and try to import the file, R imports it without problem.

```
test2.txt = 
id, ti, comment
1001, 105AB, "All OK"

test <- read.table("test2.TXT", header=T, sep=",", fileEncoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactor=F)
    id     ti comment
1 1001  105AB  All OK
```

Although this is a small example, the file I am working with is very large. Is there a way I can import the file to R with those special characters in place?

Thank you.

[test1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcg7K.png)

Comment: image of notepad missing

Comment: Sorry @Techidiot, not sure why the image upload didn't work. I followed this link to upload  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. I need to find out how to upload after question is posted.

Comment: Click on edit and then click on image icon. Copy and paste image or just use drag and drop

Comment: Thank you @Techidiot. Image of test1.txt is now attached.

Comment: Did you saved the text file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes @Techidiot, I am using Windows 8. I used Notepad++ to save it in UTF-8.Didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes. I am using Windows 8 and used Notepad++ to save in UTF-8. Got same error message in R.